# C# syntax highlight coloring

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, colors, themes, syntax-highlighting

Can I somehow change the color of field/local variables separately like in Visual Studio?
Heres how it looks like in Visual Studio (field variable assignment, readwrite is green, and local variable assignment, readwrite is white):

[image: Visual Studio Coloring]

but in VSCode, the scope for both local and field variable is "variable.other.object.cs" and "variable.other.readwrite.cs" resulting in:

[image]

(both player and anim are green)

I would also like to differentiate between a static and dynamic objects, which both have the "variable.other.object.cs" scope.

In Visual Studio it would look like this:

[image]

but it looks like this in VSCode:

[image]

Is there anything I can do about this?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

To achieve what you want, the highlighter needs to "understand" code semantics. Semantic highlighting in VSCode was introduced [early this year](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Semantic-Highlighting-Overview), and its support for languages are still limited. OmniSharp, the engine behind the C# highlighter, started supporting Roslyn-based semantics as an [experimental feature](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/pull/3667).

You would first need to opt-in to enable the feature, then restart VSCode for it to take effect.

```
"csharp.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
```

I assume you know how to invoke the scope inspector, but for the sake of other readers, it's in `View` > `Command Pallette` > `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`

You now have two options to specify custom highlighting; either using the newly available `semantic token`, or the old-school `textMateRule` scopes.

[image: semantic]

Semantic tokens will give you a modifier as well (`static` in this example)

```
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "enabled": true,
    "rules": {
        "field.static": {
            "foreground": "#FF0000",
            "fontStyle": "italic",
        },
    },
},
```

Or, if you prefer using `textMateRules`, I haven't figured out how to specify modifiers.

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "entity.name.variable.field.cs",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000",
                "fontStyle": "italic",
            },
        },
    ]
},
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! I did add "csharp.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true into the settings, but the semantic tokens don't show up/change anything. Any idea why?

Comment: Interesting. Maybe try to explicitly enable `editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled` as well? (It should be true by default, but who knows..) Also, make sure both vscode and the C# extension is up to date.

Comment: yes, everything is up to date and I have "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true in settings.json. Still can't get it to work.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. It works on all 3 of my environments. If you have another system, maybe try there and see if you can figure out how they're different? If all fails, maybe try and raise an issue with the people at [OmniSharp](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues)