# Weird C# (Unity) syntax coloring

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, themes

I want to achieve two things with my syntax highlighting

First (very important): fields in one color, arguments in other

Second (not so much important): fields of fields in a different color as well

I do realize the second need might be impossible to achieve in VSCode, but I'm pretty sure the first one should be by default, yet it behaves very strangely in my case:

[image]

You can see a couple of things - not only usage of argument and field is in the same color, but also field declaration is completely different than its usage's color, which is all over the place. You can see that if variable's name matches its class name, it has the same color as the class which is ridiculous (cause it's seems like a static class now).

Is there any way to have fields' declerations and its usages in one color, and arguments in other?

I should probably mention that semantic highlighting seems to not work - nothing changes, no matter if I turn it on true or false, restart the window or vscode altogether, nothing).

Comment: Is it really VSCode? Because it really looks like VS.... Anyway, let's assume you have VSCode, what about themes? Like downloading them from the VSCode extensions tab. Did you try that?

Comment: How is this related to Unity3d at all?

Comment: @derHugo because I had many problems with intellisense in vscode with Unity, so I thought that might be another issue.

Comment: @Nur1 yes, it is vscode with high contrast theme. I tried different themes, some of them halfway fulfilled my needs, but I've found a fix which I'm gonna post in a minute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# syntax highlight coloring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64664401/c-sharp-syntax-highlight-coloring)

Comment: I also had problems with VSCode and IntelliSense in Unity but got it to work somehow. First, try to set the default editor in Unity to VSCode (Preferences -> External Tools) This should also generate an args combination for you) Then make sure you got the default c# dev stuff from the extensions store plus the unity debugger addon. After setup, use the context menu in unity to open the c# file as c# project. Then start debugging and setup your debug configuration. Once you have debugged once with the Unity-Debugger IntelliSense and autocomplete will work fine. A little OOC but maybe helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a fix with semantic token color customization and now (inspired by Rider) the code looks something like this:

[image]

I'm using High Contrast theme (which is built-in I believe) with these rules in settings.json:

```
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "enabled": true,
    "rules": {
        "parameter": {
            "foreground": "#FFFFFF",
            "fontStyle": "italic",
        },
        "class": {
            "foreground": "#C191FF",
            "fontStyle": "underline",
        },
        "class.static": {
            "fontStyle": "bold underline",
        },
        "field": "#66C3CC",
        "property": "#66C3CC",
        "plainKeyword": "#6C95EB",
        "number": "#ED94C0",
        "method": "#33CC8F",
        "local": "#FFFFFF",
        "controlKeyword": "#6C95EB"
    }
}
```

The credit goes to Npras from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64664401/c-sharp-syntax-highlight-coloring). To be honest, it took me a while to even find that post, so I hope some people in the future like me that couldn't even find the name of the feature as well will at least find my post.

Two things worth mentioning - I don't think my second need can be achieved currently with semantic tokens, and also I've learned that most themes color properties and fields differently, which I personally do not like.

Comment: Self answers is cool. If you find good answer that help you you can upvote them some. this one had 0 upvote, making it ineligible as a dupe target.  The dupe mechanic is the way we deal with making content more accessible. One question and answer can be too hard to find. So if you have a good question to make it more visible, we can tag it so every sign post point in the rigth dirrection.

Comment: @Self thank you for the information, I'll pay more attention to upvoting from now on and I gave an upvote to Npras for his helpful answer.